# app.set('port', port) 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. Beginner, need ideas

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm an amateur learning to build with node.js.  I've been following a tutorial to create my first node.js app. It worked perfectly until I entered 'npm start'. The log is:

```
C:\node\nodeteest3\bin\www:16
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> M+<C;\node\nodetest3\bin\www:16:5
    at Module_compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup(node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Then it output about 20 lines starting with "npm ERR! " + filepaths, that I don't think are necessary, as the error seems to be in the bin file.  The code for this is

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('nodetest3:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
* Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

### This is where the error points to:

```
[app.set('port', port);]
```

### -------^error pointer at 's'-so clearly about set------------

```
app.set('port', port);
 /**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

 /**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

 /**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
   }

   return false;
}

/**
* Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
*/

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

Like I said in the beginning, I'm a complete beginner with command-line/github, but I'm already in love with it. I try to practice it every night after I finish my homework, and am getting really frustrated about getting stuck because I haven't been able to move forward for four days now. Also, I'm running this on node.js and the OS is Windows 8. Anything helps!  Let me know if you want me to post any of the other code; I omitted so as to not add more than necessary.

 "../app (app.js file) JUST ADDED"***************************
../app file:
    [ App.js   ]
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

///  catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
var app = express();
// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}


var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({estended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);





//  production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the content of the file `../app` that you have imported as `app` variable. Check whether you are correctly exporting express app at `../app` file using `module.exports`. It seems like node sees `app` variable not as an instance of an express app.

Comment: @deepal  This is my app.js page ------------------------------------------

Comment: @deepal  That seemed to work!  I've got it connected at port 300, and when I connect to that page I get a Not Found 404 error.  This means that I'm at the very least I

Comment: I'm connected, right?  Sorry tapped enter while typing on accident.  I'll post that error comment after I grab it.

Answer (score 39):

You are not exporting anything in the `app.js` file. At the end of `app.js` file, include following line.

```
module.exports = app;
```

See whether your problem goes away.

And one more addition: you have `var app = express();` twice in your `app.js`.

Comment: Always something like this :')

Answer (score 3):

You don't have declared any function called `set` inside the `app.js` file.
Create that function and export it like this:

```
exports.set = function(...) { ... };
```

If this `app` is the express `app` yo especify a port like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(port);
```

instead of

```
app.set('port', port);
 /**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

This is because the port is a property of the http server and not of the express app

You can use also

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: @fuelusumar so: var server = createServer(app);?

Comment: @fuelusumar  GOT IT! thanks!  This has been driving me crazy for the last few days!

Comment: var server = createServer(app).port(port);

Comment: you can use also app.listen(port);

Answer (score 3):

Intaned of calling export please use module.export end the end of your script.

`exports = app;`
`module.exports = app;`

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your app.js:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 26398); //<--- replace with your port number

// Server
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I simply moved the normalizePort function before the function was called. This was in coffeescript but I've converted it to javascript here.

```
normalizePort = function(val) {
  var port;
  var port;
  port = parseInt(val, 10);
  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }
  return false;
};

port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4000');
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on this. I know this took me forever to even return to, but I happen to have a lot of time at my IT job at the moment. So this looks like it will work perfectly.  Much appreciated, Loubot!

Answer (score 1):

Just add "module.exports=app;" in the app.js file.