# What is the cause of TypeError: occurring in gulpfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, webstorm

## Context

I am developing a web application using **Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.3** and **Gulp.js v.3.9.1** for task automation in **Webstorm 2016.2.3 IDE** on **macOS Sierra version 10.12** operating system and using **node** and **express** for my server. and have been following John Papa's Gulp.js course on [Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/javascript-build-automation-gulpjs/table-of-contents) as a reference into creating my gulpfile.

## Problem

When running gulp commands on the terminal to run tasks I am receiving the following error in my terminal:

```js
var port = process.env.PORT || config.defaultPort;
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPort' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projects/TEST/bbusy/gulpfile.js:42:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
```

## Things that I have tried:

1. I have read through the following Stackoverflow questions:

[error: Cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907135/error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

[app.set('port', port) 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. Beginner, need ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184026/app-setport-port-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-beginner-need-i)

2. I have tried to resolve type errors in Webstorm through enabling Node.js core and Node.js global within **Webstorm preferences | Libraries | JavaScript** - as through some further research this suggestion had popped up for syntax errors and Type errors. This has not resolved the error.
3. I have also tried the following tutorial https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html and created a `tsconfig.json` file which has not resolved the error.
4. I have re-checked the related code in `gulp.config.js`, `gulpfile.js` and `app.js` server files to make sure there are no errors.

## Sample code

Gulpfile.js:

```js
'use strict';


var gulp = require('gulp');
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var del = require('del');
var jshint = require('jshint');
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});
var port = process.env.PORT || config.defaultPort;
```

gulp.config.js:

```js
module.exports = function() {
  var client = './src/client/';
  var clientApp = client + 'app/';
  var report = './report/';
  var root = './';
  var server = './src/server/';
  var temp = './.tmp/';
  var wiredep = require('wiredep');
  var bowerFiles = wiredep({devDependencies: true})['js'];

/**
 * Node settings
 */
    defaultPort: 7203,
    nodeServer: './src/server/app.js'

    };
```

App.js:

```js
'use strict';

 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var compress = require('compression');
 var cors = require('cors');
 var errorHandler = require('./utils/errorHandler.js')();
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var port =  process.env.PORT || 7203;
 var routes;


var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

I would like to know where the error is coming from and what I am missing?

Comment: for require('./gulp.config')
gulp config file should export a module. How does your gulp config file look?

Comment: I will add this to the code snippet above please take a look

Comment: You take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-config for gul config settings.
The function in module.exports should return an object with key val pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
```

seems a bit strange to me try deleting the second `()`

like this:

```
var config = require('./gulp.config');
```

Comment: [12:50:06] Using gulpfile ~/bbusy/gulpfile.js
[12:50:06] Starting 'wiredep'...
[12:50:08] 'wiredep' errored after 1.15 s
[12:50:08] TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFile' of undefined

Comment: i dont see anywhere in your code where you call x.isFile()

Comment: neither do I although this is the rest of the message in the terminal at isFile (/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:12:20)
    at loadAsFileSync (/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:36:13)
    at loadNodeModulesSync (/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:75:21)
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:27:17)
    at requireFn (/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:64:25)